# How do I use jquery ajax to retrieve a json object and refresh this object every n seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

> Restful Service (from Server)

```
  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Consumes("application/json") 
  @Path("/getStatus/")
  // server:8080/server/rest/admin/status/whatSoEver
  public void getStatus(
      @Context HttpServletRequest request,
      @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
      IOException
  {

      //create the JSON Object to pass to the client
      JSONObject object=new JSONObject();


             response.setContentType("text/javascript");  

             String callback = request.getParameter("jsoncallback");  

             try
             {  
               for (Server i : svr)
               {
                 object.put("name",getName());
                 object.put("status",getStatus());

               }

             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {  
                  throw new ServletException("JSON Hosed up");  
             }  


               String json = object.toString();  

               /*response.getOutputStream().println(callback + "(" + json + ");");*/

               response.getOutputStream().print(json);
               response.flushBuffer();

               System.out.println("Sending "+json);
  }
```

On the client side

```
<script>


 $(document).ready(function() 
 {

    function myFunc() 
    {
         $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/getStatus",
        function (json) 
        {  
            $('#refreshMe').replaceWith(json.status);
            /* alert("Server name: " + json.name + "Server Status:"+json.status); */
        });
    }

    myFunc();
 });


    /*Do a refresh every 2 seconds */
    setInterval( "myFunc()", 500 );


</script>
```

> How do I get this jquery ajax call to
>   behave the same as the above?

```
<script>


   $.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false  });  

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/getStatus",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "???",
        success: ???
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Please do not use `setInterval` with a string but a function pointer: `setInterval(myFunc, 500);` or `setInterval(function(){ /*some code*/ }, 500);` Additionally, you might want to start the new request when the previous one finished and not earlier.

Comment: Hi, this is a great example of what I would like to do. What Java libs were you using to build the REST service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
    <script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/getStatus",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('#refreshMe').replaceWith(json.status);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: One last question. To make this ajax request continually kick off would I setInterval inside the $.ajax statement or nest another function around the $.ajax call and setInterval on that

Comment: I would do it inside the `success` callback, just because it might take > 2secs to reply and then you'll have race problems there.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the success attribute a function that will be called

```
$.ajax
({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/getStatus",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response, status, XHR) {
        $('#refreshMe').replaceWith(status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rajaa, I can now see the request coming through. How would obtain the attributes out of the json object then from here? json.name?

Comment: those are all part of the object from the server that will be stored in response variable. You could access it via response object as `response.name` .... and `response.status` ...